# Uninitialized Texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

Is there an easy and fast way to create an uninitialized texture in OpenGL?

My current approach looks like this:

```
std::vector<byte> nothing = std::vector<byte>([size of texture in bytes]);
glTexImage(
   target,
   level,
   internalFormat,
   size,
   border,
   format,
   type,
   nothing
   );
```

but this involves the upload of nothing.

Another approach would be to create an uninitialized buffer (by calling glBufferData without data) and to create the texture from this buffer. But afaik this has twice the memory footprint (and i am on a low memory budget).

Is there a good way to create a texture that will be written to later without using bandwidth or extra memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass a null pointer for data. This is how it's specified in OpenGL since version 1. From the OpenGL 1.2 specification, section 3.8.1, page 118, last paragraph:

> If the *data* argument of TexImage1D,
>   TexImage2D, or TexImage3D is a null
>   pointer (a zero-valued pointer in the
>   C implementation), a one-, two-, or
>   three-dimensional texture array is
>   created with the specified target,
>   level, internalformat, width, height,
>   and depth, but with unspecified image
>   contents. In this case no pixel values
>   are accessed in client memory, and no
>   pixel processing is performed. Errors
>   are generated, however, exactly as
>   though the data pointer were valid.

Comment: woha ... who comes that i just didn't knew this? The docs on opengl.org don't say anything about this, do they? Could you please point me to the specific text where this is mentioned?

Comment: Ah thanks. I was searching the docs and several forums but haven't looked into the specification